# Is there a name for the incomplete measure completing the anacrusis?

Tags: terminology, anacrusis

In a piece that starts with an anacrusis/pickup measure and ends, or ends a repeating section, with a compensating incomplete measure, is there a term for that final measure?

- *incomplete measure* can describe both the starting and ending measures.
- *anacrusis* and *pickup* refers only to the starting measure.
- *???* refers only to the ending measure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific term for it.  Cute options would be calling it a katacrusis or a dropoff bar, with a somewhat moderate chance of people getting your meaning.  They would also be sort-of candidates for an official term if such a one would often be asked for.  But I don't think that happens often enough that some term would have had a chance to be solidly established.

P.S.: I see that Wikipedia in its entry for "anacrusis" refers to the completing bar as "complement" which seems as nice a term as any.

Comment: Hehe, I like your inventions! It looks like *katacrusis* might already have a definition in ancient Greek or biblical scholarship, as a rhetorical "parenthetical aside": https://www.google.com/books/edition/Paul_Through_Mediterranean_Eyes/07QM_otHMp8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=katacrusis&pg=PA70&printsec=frontcover https://www.inthebeginning.org/chiasmus/xfiles/john12_20-36.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to describe it would be to use its bar number. As for an actual name of this kind of incomplete bar; I don’t know of one.

Incidentally, a pickup bar at the beginning of a piece is bar 0.

Comment: Never noticed 'bar 0' before - but it's right. Still learning...  +1.