Where to stop in Da Capo al fine
I am working on a piece that ends D.C. al Fine, and there is an earlier bar comprising a dotted minim, then Fine, then a crochet (all in 4/4 time).
My interpretation is to go back to the start of the page, play up to and including the note that has the dotted minim (which happens to be the tonic), then stop. Maybe let the note fade, so the dotted minim becomes a semibreve.
Is this the correct interpretation?

This post comes close to answering my question, but not quite.

Could you post an image?

Is the end of the word "Fine" before or after the crochet? The word "Fine" is often so long that it has to start before the last note of the measure.

@Dekkadeci The end is before the crochet, and the beginning after the dotted minim.

See also https://music.stackexchange.com/q/117862/78419. Is there an anacrusis of a crotchet?

Your interpretation is correct. The “fine” appears before the crochet so it is not played. If you interpret this literally, hold the final note for 3 beats and cut off on beat 4. If you want to take liberties and interpret it as a semibreve or do something else you can, as long as you aren’t playing with others who may use the literal interpretation.
